# Last word repeated in a text file C++

Tags: c++

This is my code for writing and reading a text file but the problem here is that this code generating the last word again as in it is *repeating* the last work of the text file which it shouldn't. Can anyone tell what mistake im making?

The output of this program is:

Ahsan's

first

file.

file.

```
ofstream myfile;
ifstream infile;
string lol; 


myfile.open ("ahsan.txt");
myfile << "Ahsan's first file.\n";
myfile.close();

infile.open("ahsan.txt");
while(!infile.eof())
{
   infile>>lol;
   cout<<lol<<endl;


}
infile.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of using `.eof()`:

```
while(infile >> lol)
{
    cout<<lol<<endl;
}
```